# Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', 'updateStrategy' and 'minReadySeconds' are forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to upgrade my rabbitmq to 3.10 version. When I am deploying using the new image I get below error. I made a small change to the template and not sure why it is throwing this error and nothing else was changed apart from the template.

The StatefulSet "uat-can-gcp-common-rabbitmq-ha-extend" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', 'updateStrategy' and 'minReadySeconds' are forbidden

Below is the code for my statefulset

```
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
{{- if .Values.extraLabels }}
{{ toYaml .Values.extraLabels | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- if .Values.statefulSetAnnotations }}
  annotations:
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.statefulSetAnnotations }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: {{ .Values.podManagementPolicy }}
  serviceName: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.fullname" . }}-discovery
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  updateStrategy:
    type: {{ .Values.updateStrategy }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.name" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
{{- if .Values.extraLabels }}
{{ toYaml .Values.extraLabels | indent 8 }}
{{- end }}
      annotations:
        {{- if not .Values.existingConfigMap }}
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- if not .Values.existingSecret }}
        checksum/secret: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secret.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- if and .Values.prometheus.exporter.enabled (not .Values.prometheus.operator.enabled) }}
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: {{ .Values.prometheus.exporter.port | quote }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- if and .Values.rabbitmqPrometheusPlugin.enabled (not .Values.prometheus.operator.enabled) }}
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: {{ .Values.rabbitmqPrometheusPlugin.port | quote }}
        prometheus.io/path: {{ .Values.rabbitmqPrometheusPlugin.path | quote }}
        {{- end }}
{{- if .Values.podAnnotations }}
{{ toYaml .Values.podAnnotations | indent 8 }}
{{- end }}
    spec:
      {{- if .Values.image.pullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
      {{- range .Values.image.pullSecrets }}
        - name: {{ . }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ .Values.terminationGracePeriodSeconds }}
      securityContext:
{{ toYaml .Values.securityContext | indent 10 }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.serviceAccountName" . }}
      initContainers:
{{- if .Values.initContainer.enabled }}
        - name: bootstrap
          image: {{ .Values.busyboxImage.repository}}:{{ .Values.busyboxImage.tag}}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.busyboxImage.pullPolicy }}
          securityContext:
{{- toYaml .Values.initContainer.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          command: ['sh']
          args:
          - "-c"
          - |
            set -ex
            cp /configmap/* /etc/rabbitmq
            echo "${RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE}" > /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
            {{- if .Values.forceBoot }}
            if [ -d "${RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR}" ]; then
              touch "${RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR}/force_load"
            fi
            {{- end }}
            {{- if and (.Values.securityContext.runAsUser) (.Values.securityContext.fsGroup) (.Values.initContainer.chownFiles) }}
            chown -R {{ .Values.securityContext.runAsUser }}:{{ .Values.securityContext.fsGroup }} /var/lib/rabbitmq/
            chown -R {{ .Values.securityContext.runAsUser }}:{{ .Values.securityContext.fsGroup }} /etc/rabbitmq
            {{- end }}
            chmod 600 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
          env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                apiVersion: v1
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR
            value: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@$(POD_NAME).{{ template "rabbitmq-ha.fullname" . }}-discovery.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.{{ .Values.clusterDomain }}
          - name: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.secretName" . }}
                key: rabbitmq-erlang-cookie
          resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.initContainer.resources | indent 12 }}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: configmap
              mountPath: /configmap
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq
            - name: {{ .Values.persistentVolume.name }}
              mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
{{- end}}
{{- if .Values.extraInitContainers }}
{{ tpl (toYaml .Values.extraInitContainers) . | indent 8 }}
{{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.dnsConfig }}
      dnsConfig:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: {{ .Values.image.name }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: epmd
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 4369
            - name: amqp
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 5672
            - name: http
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 15672
            {{- if .Values.rabbitmqSTOMPPlugin.enabled }}
            - name: stomp-tcp
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 61613
            - name: stomp-ssl
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 61614
            {{- end }}
            {{- if .Values.rabbitmqWebSTOMPPlugin.enabled }}
            - name: stomp-ws
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 15674
            {{- end }}
            {{- if .Values.rabbitmqMQTTPlugin.enabled }}
            - name: mqtt-tcp
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 1883
            - name: mqtt-ssl
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 8883
            {{- end }}
            {{- if .Values.rabbitmqWebMQTTPlugin.enabled }}
            - name: mqtt-ws
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 15675
            {{- end }}
            {{- if .Values.rabbitmqAmqpsSupport.enabled }}
            - name: amqps
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 5671
            {{- end }}
            {{- if .Values.rabbitmqPrometheusPlugin.enabled }}
            - name: metrics
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: {{ .Values.rabbitmqPrometheusPlugin.port }}
            {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.livenessProbe.enabled }}
          livenessProbe:
            {{- toYaml .Values.livenessProbe.config | trim | nindent 12 }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.readinessProbe.enabled }}
          readinessProbe:
            {{- toYaml .Values.readinessProbe.config | trim | nindent 12 }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.lifecycle }}
          lifecycle:
            {{- toYaml .Values.lifecycle | trim | nindent 12 }}
        {{- end }}
          env:
            - name: MY_POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME
              value: "true"
            - name: RABBITMQ_NODENAME
              value: rabbit@$(MY_POD_NAME).{{ template "rabbitmq-ha.fullname" . }}-discovery.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.{{ .Values.clusterDomain }}
            - name: K8S_HOSTNAME_SUFFIX
              value: .{{ template "rabbitmq-ha.fullname" . }}-discovery.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.{{ .Values.clusterDomain }}
            - name: K8S_SERVICE_NAME
              value: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.fullname" . }}-discovery
            - name: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.secretName" . }}
                  key: rabbitmq-erlang-cookie
            - name: RABBIT_MANAGEMENT_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.secretName" . }}
                  key: rabbitmq-management-username
            - name: RABBIT_MANAGEMENT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.secretName" . }}
                  key: rabbitmq-management-password
            {{- if .Values.rabbitmqHipeCompile }}
            - name: RABBITMQ_HIPE_COMPILE
              value: {{ .Values.rabbitmqHipeCompile | quote }}
            {{- end }}
            {{- range $key, $value := .Values.env }}
            - name: {{ $key }}
              value: {{ $value | quote }}
            {{- end }}            
          resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: {{ .Values.persistentVolume.name }}
              mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq
            - name: definitions
              mountPath: /etc/definitions
              readOnly: true
            {{- if .Values.rabbitmqCert.enabled }}
            - name: cert
              mountPath: /etc/cert
            {{- end }}
            {{- if .Values.extraVolumeMounts }}
{{ toYaml .Values.extraVolumeMounts | indent 12 }}
            {{- end }}
        {{ if .Values.prometheus.exporter.enabled }}
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-exporter
          image: {{ .Values.prometheus.exporter.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.prometheus.exporter.image.tag }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.prometheus.exporter.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
          - name: exporter
            protocol: TCP
            containerPort: {{ .Values.prometheus.exporter.port }}
          env:
            - name: PUBLISH_PORT
              value: "{{ .Values.prometheus.exporter.port }}"
            {{ if .Values.prometheus.exporter.capabilities }}
            - name: RABBIT_CAPABILITIES
              value: "{{ .Values.prometheus.exporter.capabilities }}"
            {{- end }}
            - name: RABBIT_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.secretName" . }}
                  key: rabbitmq-username
            - name: RABBIT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.secretName" . }}
                  key: rabbitmq-password
            {{- range $key, $value := .Values.prometheus.exporter.env }}
            - name: {{ $key }}
              value: {{ $value | quote }}
            {{- end }}
          resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.prometheus.exporter.resources | indent 12 }}
        {{ end }}
        {{- if .Values.extraContainers }}
{{ tpl (toYaml .Values.extraContainers) . | indent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
{{ toYaml .Values.nodeSelector | indent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
{{ toYaml .Values.tolerations | indent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.schedulerName }}
      schedulerName: "{{ .Values.schedulerName }}"
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
      {{- with .Values.affinity }}
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- else }}
      {{- if eq .Values.podAntiAffinity "hard" }}
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - topologyKey: "{{ .Values.podAntiAffinityTopologyKey }}"
              labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.name" . }}
                  release: {{ .Release.Name }}
      {{- else if eq .Values.podAntiAffinity "soft" }}
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 1
              podAffinityTerm:
                topologyKey: "{{ .Values.podAntiAffinityTopologyKey }}"
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.name" . }}
                    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}

      {{- if .Values.priorityClassName }}
      priorityClassName: {{ .Values.priorityClassName }}
      {{- end }}
      volumes:
        - name: config
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: configmap
          configMap:
            name: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.fullname" . }}
        - name: definitions
          secret:
            secretName: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.secretName" . }}
            items:
            - key: {{ .Values.definitionsSource }}
              path: definitions.json
        {{- if .Values.rabbitmqCert.enabled }}
        - name: cert
          secret:
            defaultMode: 420
            secretName: {{ template "rabbitmq-ha.certSecretName" . }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.extraVolumes }}
{{ toYaml .Values.extraVolumes | indent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
{{- if .Values.persistentVolume.enabled }}
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: {{ .Values.persistentVolume.name }}
        annotations:
{{ tpl (toYaml .Values.persistentVolume.annotations) . | indent 10 }}
        labels:
{{ tpl (toYaml .Values.persistentVolume.labels) . | indent 10 }}
      spec:
        accessModes:
        {{- range .Values.persistentVolume.accessModes }}
          - {{ . | quote }}
        {{- end }}
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: {{ .Values.persistentVolume.size | quote }}
      {{- if .Values.persistentVolume.storageClass }}
      {{- if (eq "-" .Values.persistentVolume.storageClass) }}
        storageClassName: ""
      {{- else }}
        storageClassName: "{{ .Values.persistentVolume.storageClass }}"
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.persistentVolume.selector }}
        selector:
          {{- toYaml . | nindent 10 }}
      {{- end }}
{{- else }}
        - name: {{ .Values.persistentVolume.name }}
          emptyDir: {}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to render out both iterations and run `diff` on them to find out whether you are accidentally changing fields that are immutable in the API.